# I'm trying to include Menu from semantic ui react in my website, but I'm getting an error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to learn react while building a project. Idk how to include menu in the website. I have tried two approaches to do this, both are not working.

Approach 1 :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV4Pu.png)

Error associated with this approach:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zkdQ.png)

Approach 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p2t7.png)

Error associated with this approach:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdPDn.png)

I'm trying to create a menu like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcbjQ.png)

Comment: The best and clear approach is given in the example, you can easily copy paste the code itself
https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu/#types-content-prop

Comment: In your first approach, the library export name and the component name is same, that is an issue

Answer (score 0):

In first, component name and library module name are same. In second, you can not defined component name.

you can add like:

```
import { Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const MenuBar = () =>{
  return(
    //code
  );
}

export default MenuBar;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed the name of the component like you said but that is also giving error, same as the error mentioned in the approach 2.

Comment: can you share me source code?